# selenium-python clicking a button always returns an error

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, gwt

I am trying to click a button using python-selenium binding; tried various selectors without any luck so far. I am using Chromedriver.

I can select an element using `elem = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//div[@id='gwt-debug-search-button']")` no error but when trying to click it says `element is not visible`

I have used action chains, it goes through without any errors but clicking on the button did not occur. I cannot figure out the problem. If you have solved similar issues before, please share.

```
get_ideas = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//span[@id='gwt-debug-search-button-content'][normalize-space()='Get ideas']")
chains = ActionChains(driver)
chains.click(on_element=elem).perform()
```

Here is the html source:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="goog-button-base goog-inline-block goog-button aw-btn aw-larger-button aw-save-button" role="button" id="gwt-debug-search-button">
    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
        <div class="goog-button-base-outer-box goog-inline-block">
            <div class="goog-button-base-inner-box goog-inline-block">
                <div class="goog-button-base-pos">
                    <div class="goog-button-base-top-shadow">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="goog-button-base-content">
                        <span id="gwt-debug-search-button-content">Get ideas</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never used `ActionChains` preferring instead this approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait #set wait time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC #specify the expected condition

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # Or whatever you prefer
driver.get(your_website_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.title_contains(my_website_title))
```

In your case you might want to make the driver to wait for your page to contain the button you want to click.

About clicking the button, I would suggest you to use something like:

```
# option 1
get_ideas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='gwt-debug-search-button-content']")
# option 2
get_ideas = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Get ideas")

get_ideas.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few errors, one being to not use action chains unless absolutely needed.  But the other is you are not actually passing anything to your click event.

It should be:

```
chains.click(get_ideas).perform()
```

The real problem with doing action chains, is it caches the event.  What that means is if you want to not rename every new action you'll ever do, you either have to clear your action chain out before reuse every time or rename the chain on every new use.

You should just be using the power of selenium for regular clicks and things, I would only use action chains for double clicking and other such behavior which is really what it was intended to do anyways.

Doing that, mabe02's answer is by far easier, and easier to read!